# How can I find a (simple) continuous function that works approximately this way?

Tags: functions, polynomials, graphing-functions

I would like to find a continuous function that works (very approximately) the following way:

[image]

- The exact shape is not really important, it's more of a general fitting.
- I would really like it to be continuous if possible
- The more simple it is the better, even at the cost of some precision of what the fitting looks like

So far I've been playing around in desmos with different polynomial functions with no luck, I've also tried the google sheets tools that make interpolations but the actual functions I get only behave as expected in this very narrow portion where I provide data.

Comment: If it helps: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/z8cgzwimhw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\exp\left(\frac{1}{x}\arctan\left(x\right)\right)+\frac{x^{2}}{50}$$
This function is adequate .

Comment: Nice, this is awesome! How did you get to that? Did you have a built up intuition of how do this functions behaved and played around or is there some tools around?